# QEMU Raspbian on OS X

Tags: raspbian, macos, qemu

Sorry for bothering folks:

I tried a lot of instructions to get a Raspbian image running on QEMU (2.0.0 via homebrew) on OS X (10.9.3).

I downloaded several versions of Raspbian but always the first boot fails.

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel ../kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2013-12-20-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

brings the error message

```
Unable to determine your tty name.
```

and starting into a shell

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel ../kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 init=/bin/sh rw" -hda 2013-12-20-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

makes the system wait indefinitely before the login prompt appears.

I know that I have to edit

```
/etc/ld.so.preload
```

but for this a first boot would be helpful.

Any ideas, hints, facepalms?

with regards
yogi viegelinsch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing qemu **version 1.7.1** (the version *prior* to 2.0.0).

I had very similar problems with qemu 2.0.0 (installed via [macports](http://www.macports.org) in my case), and switching back to the prior version made everything work.

I do not use homebrew, but this [response at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) has detailed instructions to revert to an earlier version of any package using Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

When booting first time you should use `bash` as init application and change `/etc/ld.so.preload`. Please note `-append` parameter:

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash console=ttyAMA0,115200" -hda 2014-12-24-wheezy-raspbian.img`

Kudos for this hint should go to [xecdesign](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/) for tutorial that explain how to boot versatilepb with arm1176.

Comment: that didnt work for me

Comment: Did you change `ld.so.preload` according to instructions from tutorial ? You should disable `libcofi_rpi.so` usage, because of replacement of `memcpy` and `memset`. You can find more information about this problem [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=9260).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues and I finally got this working last night, on OS X 10.8.5 with **QEMU v2.2.0**, after working on/off for two weeks.

#### Preamble

I was prompted by the question, [Can I program for Arduino without having a real board?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board), to try to use a real emulator, such as [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org), as suggested by *[zmo](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/379/zmo)*, in a comment to *[Anindo Ghosh](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/70/anindo-ghosh)*'s answer.

I thought that I would relate my experience here.

I set this up on a MacBook Pro, running 10.8. (Mountain Lion). I quickly found the link [Installing QEMU on OS X](https://github.com/psema4/pine/wiki/Installing-QEMU-on-OS-X)<sup>1</sup>. <strike>Yes, I know is seems to be related to the Pi, but bear with me.</strike> After a quick browse, it was clear what was required.

First step was to set up the Mac with the correct environment. This required, in the following order:

1. Xcode;
2. Xcode command line tools;
3. homebrew;
4. a compiler, and finally;
5. qemu itself

#### Details

Going into each step in detail

1. Xcode - I used 5.1, from the Apple site [link?]
2. The command line tools were downloaded from within Xcode, from Tools
   -> Downloads.
3. Homebrew was installed in the terminal, using the following command

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

There was a failed download at first, due to the Thai telephone network dropping, which required a messy cleanup. But running the command again worked.

4. Then `brew doctor`, at first complaining that I had a case sensitive file system, threw up a requirement for [Quartz 2.7.7](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing), I
   had 2.7.4 installed evidently. This I downloaded, rebooted, ran
   `brew doctor` again. It was still complaining, but this time because
   I had Quartz 2.6.3 installed! I gave up at that point and moved on.
5. Selecting the QEMU build required these two commands

`cd /usr/local/ # Or wherever you installed Homebrew.`

`git checkout 2b7b4b3 Library/Formula/qemu.rb`

6. Then installing `gcc`, which I left to run its course.

`brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb`

7. Then install `pkg-config`

`brew install pkg-config`

8. And finally (!) QEMU

`brew install qemu --env=std --cc=gcc-4.2`

Then unfortunately [that page](https://github.com/psema4/pine/wiki/Installing-QEMU-on-OS-X)'s instructions failed me as the links to the `zImage` and `rootfs` files on dropbox had been killed, due to over subscription, so I had to find another method. I decided to sleep on it, as I was getting irritated by now.

Then following morning, after a not so refreshing sleep, I found the link, [QEMU – Emulating Raspberry Pi the easy way (Linux or Windows!)](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/)<sup>1</sup> which, pretty much enabled me to carry on from where I left off.

1. Downloading the PI images from the [Raspberry PI downloads page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)
2. Downloading the linux kernel (which required `brew install wget` beforehand):

`wget http://xecdesign.com/downloads/linux-qemu/kernel-qemu`

3. Verifying qemu's available emulation modes:

`qemu-system-arm -cpu ?`

4. First boot

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

This resulted in a cycle of SCSI errors,

> ABORT, DEVICE RESET, BUS RESET, HOST RESET, sym0: SCSI  BUS has been
>   reset, HOST RESET, Device offlined

and so on, cycling through ever increasing SCSI device IDs, *n*, (`scsi 0:0:*n*:0`). *n* = {0, 1, 2... 6, 8, 9... 15} 7 was skipped as it is presumably the host controller.

[image: Screenshot of QEMU window first run #1]

It would cycle up to SCSI ID=14,

[image: Screenshot of QEMU window first run #2]

with the console in the QEMU window eventually crashing, at SCSI ID=15,

[image: Screenshot of QEMU window first run #3]

leaving the following error in the terminal from which it was run.

```
snowserv:local user$ qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda ~/Documents/PI\:Arduino/Lapdock/Raspberry\ PI\ Disk\ Images/2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy.img
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
pflash_write: Unimplemented flash cmd sequence (offset 00000000, wcycle 0x0 cmd 0x0 value 0xf000f0)
pflash_write: Unimplemented flash cmd sequence (offset 00000000, wcycle 0x0 cmd 0x0 value 0xf0)
snowserv:local user$
```

I tried the same command prefixed with `sudo`, but the same issue occurred.

I thought that the issue was the `root=/dev/sda2`. Copying the Raspbian image locally didn't help (it had been on a separate partition).  Looking at the comments on the web page, a number of people were getting the same SCSI errors.

It appeared to be an issue with the version of QEMU. I was using 1.1.50

```
qemu-system-arm --version
```

After some to-ing and fro-ing, I found the newer version, 2.2.0

I checked out `fce79940eb`

```
git checkout fce79940eb Library/Formula/qemu.rb
```

Unlinked the older version

```
brew unlink qemu
```

Install new checked out version

```
brew install qemu --env=std --cc=gcc-4.2
```

And running **the first boot command**

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

this time resulted in the expected command prompt.

I ran through the suggested edits of `/etc/ld.so.preload` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-qemu.rules`, without any issues arising.

However, I was unable to `halt`, `shutdown` or `reboot` the Pi. The errors received were

```
init: /run/initctl: No such file or directory
```

[image: Screen shot first real boot]

I ended up doing a hard reboot, by just quitting the QEMU app.

In the terminal were a lot of

```
coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioDeviceIOProc
Reason: Invalid argument
```

errors logged. Probably from failed beeps arising from failed shutdowns.

I repeated the first boot, as a google<sup>2</sup> suggested that the `init` issue could be solved simply by just a hard boot, but I still had the start up errors, and the halt errors.

[image: Screenshot of halt errors]

There was a "better" way of shutting down though, as I was given the tip (see below) that

```
reboot -f
```

worked.

In an attempt to lose the `init` errors, after some more googling<sup>3</sup>, I ran the following commands:

`mkfifo /dev/initctl`

but, predictably, it was not persistent, and didn't fix shutdown.

`mkfifo /run/initctl`

which was persistent, but didn't fix the shutdown.

I encountered [henje](https://superuser.com/users/425846/henje) on Super User having the same issue. From [shutdown: /run/initctl: No such file or directory](https://superuser.com/questions/886825/shutdown-run-initctl-no-such-file-or-directory)

> Thx for the `reboot -f`. Good tip. After further googling, a hard
>   reboot is supposed to fix the issue, but it hasn't. I have also run
>   `mkfifo /run/initctl` which stops the *No such file or directory*
>   error, but still doesn't shut the system down. I now get `init:
>   timeout opening/writing control channel /run/initctl`. I have compared
>   the `/run/initctl` just created, with the one on my working RPi, and
>   they look identical: `prw------- 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970
>   /run/initctl`.

I carried on regardless, and ran the **proper boot command**, the same as the first boot, minus the `init=/bin/bash`

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

It booted, apparently without issue, into the `raspi-config` screen. I changed the hostname and `pi` user's password. Then hit *Finish* and agreed to the restart, the QEMU just exited, appearing to die, the window vanished.

I ran the same **proper boot command** again

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

command again. It booted to normal text console login. Logged in, ran `startx`, X can up. Ran `sudo shutdown-h now`. System shutdown without mishap, leaving `System halted` message. Although the CPU was left running at 100%, and the window did not close. I had to close it manually.

Ran same **proper boot** command again, it booted OK. It does run `fsck` each boot, so I am not sure if that is indicative of the `halt` not working correctly, or whether Raspbian does that anyway on each boot. However, upon `sudo halt`, I see the message

```
[ ok ] Unmounting local file systems...done.
```

so I assume that it is OK and normal.

I hope that this (rambling) tale, helps someone else.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is way too much info to attempt to summarise, in case of link death.

<sup>2</sup> According to [can't reboot debian](http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/183/cant-reboot-debian/p1) and [systemd-sysv, sysvinit: problems rebooting when switching between systemd-sysv and sysvinit](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663219)

<sup>3</sup> According to [I got a error flag "init: /dev/initctl: no such file"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/i-got-a-error-flag-init-dev-initctl-no-such-file-219080/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on MacOS Mojave,

Create a file called `qemu_script.sh` and copy-paste the code below

```
nano qemu_script.sh
```

give execution perms and execute,

```
$ chmod +x qemu_script.sh
$ ./qemu_script.sh
```

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/sh

brew install qemu

export QEMU=$(which qemu-system-arm)
export TMP_DIR=~/tmp/qemu-rpi
export RPI_KERNEL=${TMP_DIR}/kernel-qemu-4.14.79-stretch
export RPI_FS=${TMP_DIR}/2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.img
export PTB_FILE=${TMP_DIR}/versatile-pb.dtb
export IMAGE_FILE=2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip
export IMAGE=http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2018-11-15/${IMAGE_FILE}

mkdir -p $TMP_DIR; cd $TMP_DIR

wget https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/blob/master/kernel-qemu-4.14.79-stretch?raw=true \
        -O ${RPI_KERNEL}

wget https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/raw/master/versatile-pb.dtb \
        -O ${PTB_FILE}

wget $IMAGE
unzip $IMAGE_FILE


$QEMU -kernel ${RPI_KERNEL} \
    -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb \
    -dtb ${PTB_FILE} -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -drive "file=${RPI_FS},index=0,media=disk,format=raw" \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 -net nic \
```

**You should get:**
[image]

HTH someone

Comment: What's that? Can you explain please?

Comment: Hi, yup, let me edit to the post.